# IE not observing offset position

Tags: jquery

I have just noticed my new script has a problem in ie 7 and 8 re: offset and position.

Everything works fine in modern browsers, but i can not account for the reason IE refuses to adhere to the offset position i specify..?

The Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#%id%").css("margin" , 0);
var position = $("#%id%").offset();


$("<div/>", {
  "class": "doosuperoverlay"
})
.prependTo("body")
.delay(%id=delay%000)
.fadeOut(%id=fadeout%000);



var orgStackWidth = $("#%id%").width();
var tempClone = $("#%id%").clone();
$(tempClone).css({
"width" : orgStackWidth + "px",
"text-align" : "left"
});
$(tempClone).appendTo(".doosuperoverlay").css(position)
.delay(%id=delay%000)
.fadeOut(%id=fadeout%000);


});
```

There is a working demo [page setup here](http://www.doobox.co.uk/stacks_store/demos/landing_zone.html)

Solved: The answer lay in this portion of the script:

```
var orgStackWidth = $("#%id%").width();
var tempClone = $("#%id%").clone();
$(tempClone).css({
"position" : "relative",
"width" : orgStackWidth + "px",
"text-align" : "left"
});
```

The addition of position:relative to the temp clone sorted ie issue out. Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

[offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)  returns an object containing the properties top and left.

so replace

```
$(tempClone).prependTo(".doosuperoverlay").css(position)
.animate({opacity: 1.0}, %id=delay%000)
.fadeOut(%id=fadeout%000);
```

with

```
$(tempClone).prependTo(".doosuperoverlay").css({top: position.top, left: position.left})
.animate({opacity: 1.0}, %id=delay%000)
.fadeOut(%id=fadeout%000);
```

Think that is gonna work.

Comment: You don't need to do this, the object already has the properties it needs, there's no need to wrap it in *another* object.

Comment: That's true Nick, Tim's suggestion works equally as well but does not address the issue. Thank's though Tim.